# How to check Trigger between two kinematic RigidBodies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a object "A" with non convex mesh collider and kinematic rigidbodie and i wand to check trigger between Object "A" and another Game Object with non convex mesh collider and kinematic rigidbodie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see in this collision detection matrix:
[image]

Between two Kinematic the trigger is working and giving the message, so if you put both a trigger Collider it will give you a message.

If you want to be sure just add a tag to one and so you can also check the tag first and avoid wrong triggers:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collision other)
{
  if(other.compareTag("Trigger2")
// do things
}
```